# Blob download works in Chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I am using the following code snippet to download a blob formed form ArrayBuffer

```
                       let blob = new window.Blob(dataOrg);
                       let anchor = document.createElement('a');
                       anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                       anchor.download = "downloadssss";
                       anchor.textContent = 'XXXXXXX';

                       if (anchor.click) {
                           anchor.click();
                       } else {
                           var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                           evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                           evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                           anchor.dispatchEvent(evt);
                       }
```

This code works in chrome but doesnot do anything in Firefox. The content i am trying to download is a mp4 file sent through PeerJs.

Comment: `doesnot do anything in Firefox` any console output?

Comment: no there are no errors. Data arrives from PeerJs and nothing happens(meaning no download and no error)

Comment: perhaps because `anchor.click` is truthy, so the code runs `anchor.click();` - if `anchor.click` were falsey, then the other code would run instead (and work) - which method does Chrum use? (nevermind, it does the first as well) - firefox is picky about when `element.click()` can be executed

Comment: i checked for both firefox and chrome both of them return true for anchor.click

Comment: Jaromanda ,so what should i do?

Comment: of course they do ... here's the thing ... firefox expects an element to be in the DOM before it is clicked ... `anchor.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);` before the `if` statement should do it - proof of concept - `https://jsfiddle.net/y94tnL0s/` (navigating here will download a simple text file)

Comment: thanks a lot Joromanda that worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code.

```
let blob = new window.Blob(dataOrg);
                       let anchor = document.createElement('a');
                       anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                       anchor.download = "downloadssss";
                       anchor.textContent = 'XXXXXXX';
                       document.body.appendChild(anchor);  // This is required
                       if (anchor.click) {
                           anchor.click();
                       } else {
                           var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                           evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                           evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                           anchor.dispatchEvent(evt);
                       }
```

You need to append the anchor tag to the document body to work in the firefox. After this change you might face content security policy issue if you are using the content security policy header in your index.html response.